# Orthogonal polynomials

Tags: calculus, orthogonal-polynomials

I was put on hold 2 times already for this question, I don't know how to solve it (If i knew how to solve it I wouldn't be bothering you ) and I don't know why it doesn't fit the rules of this site or why I'm being put on hold. If you could at least tell me that I would be very happy :)

So, I have the following question :Given the recurrence relation $$\pi_{k+1}(t)=(t-\alpha_k)\pi_k-\beta_k\pi_{k-1}(t)$$, k=0,1,2... for the ortogonalpolynomials (monica) {$\pi_j(^.;d \lambda)$} and defining $$\beta_0=\int_R d\lambda(t)$$ show that $$||\pi_k||^2=\beta_0\beta_1....\beta_k , k=0,1,2...$$
How can this be exploited in a practical implementation of the approximation in the least - squares sense relatively to the orthogonal system?

Which I have tried to solve

Because $\pi_{k+1}(t)-t\pi_{k}(t)$ is a polynom with the degree $\le$k it can be expressed as a linear combination of $\pi_{1},\pi_{2},...,\pi_{k}$
$\pi_{k+1}(t)-t\pi_{k}(t)=-\alpha_k\pi_k(t) - \beta_k \pi_{k-1}(t)+\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}\gamma_j\pi_j(t) $ we multiply it with $\pi_k$ and obtain 
$$(-t\pi_k,\pi_k)=-\alpha_k(\pi_k,\pi_k)$$
$\alpha_k $= $\frac{(t\pi_k,\pi_k)}{(\pi_k,\pi_k)} $ k=0,1,2,...

$\pi_{k+1}(t)-t\pi_{k}(t)=-\alpha_k\pi_k(t) - \beta_k \pi_{k-1}(t)+\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}\gamma_j\pi_j(t) $ we multiply it with $\pi_{k-1}$ and obtain $$(-t\pi_k,\pi_{k-1})=-\beta_k(\pi_{k-1},\pi_{k-1})$$
Because $(-t\pi_k,\pi_{k-1})=(\pi_{k},\pi_{k-1})$ and $t\pi_{k-1}$ differs from $\pi_{k}$ by a polynom with the degree $\le k$ we obtain by orthogonality 
$(t\pi_k,\pi_{k-1})=-\beta_k(\pi_{k},\pi_{k})$, so 
$$\beta_k = \frac{(\pi_k,\pi_k)}{(\pi_{k-1},\pi_{k-1})}, k=0,1,2,...$$

This is how far I've got. I still don't know how to show that $$||\pi_k||^2=\beta_0\beta_1....\beta_k , k=0,1,2...$$

Comment: There are a number of reasons a question might be put on hold.  Usually it is because the OP does not include their own thoughts/attempts to solve the problem.  It looks like you've taken care of that here.  One thing that will make your question much better is if you typeset the mathematics instead of providing a link to an image.  Links break over time and are not text searchable.  Please take a few minutes and edit your post to typeset the mathematics.  If you've never done it before, there is a good guide here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Thank you very much TravisJ :)

Comment: You might also want to include how you compute $\Vert \pi_{k}\Vert$.  I assume it involves a integral...

Answer (score 0):

It is rather straightforward. Define, $\pi_0$ first. Let $\pi_0=\sqrt{\beta_0}$. (Generally, measures are taken as unit measures so that $\pi_0=1$ which seems better). Then, using $\beta_k = \frac{(\pi_k,\pi_k)}{(\pi_{k-1},\pi_{k-1})}$ for $k=1$ you find $\beta_1$. Since you have $||\pi_1||^2=\beta_0\beta_1$ at this step, using $\beta_k = \frac{(\pi_k,\pi_k)}{(\pi_{k-1},\pi_{k-1})}$ for $k=2$ you have $||\pi_2||^2=\beta_0\beta_1\beta_2$. For a general $k$, just use  induction.

For a gentle and at the same time comprehensive introduction for orthogonal polynomials on $\mathbb{R}$ (which also answers what you asked), I can suggest the Chapter 1 of the book "Szegö's Theorem and Its Descendants: Spectral Theory for $L^2$ Perturbations of Orthogonal Polynomials" by Barry Simon.